# QtWidget couldnt be configured for installation after running configure.py of PyQt5.5.1 source

Tags: python3, pyqt, ld, qmake, pyqt5

I am triyng to install PyQt5 on xubuntu 14.04 but after the procedure completes successfully there is no **QWidgets.so** file in directory ***"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/"*** as well as other Qt*.so files... there is only few ones such as ***QtDBus.so     QtNfc.so  QtWebChannel.so  QtXmlPatterns.so

QtCore.so    QtNetwork.so  Qt.so     QtWebSockets.so  QtXml.so***

i executed the configure.py file with command below:

```
python3 ./configure.py --qmake /opt/Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/bin/qmake --verbose
```

i made an output of configure.py execution and noticed something..down below is what i mean

```
Checking to see if the QtWidgets module should be built...
/opt/Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/bin/qmake -o cfgtest_QtWidgets.mk cfgtest_QtWidgets.pro
make -f cfgtest_QtWidgets.mk
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -std=gnu++0x -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I/opt/Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/include -I/opt/Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets -I/opt/Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/include/QtGui -I/opt/Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -I/opt/Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o cfgtest_QtWidgets.o cfgtest_QtWidgets.cpp
g++ -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-z,origin -Wl,-rpath,\$ORIGIN -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/lib -o cfgtest_QtWidgets cfgtest_QtWidgets.o   -L/opt/Qt5.6.0/5.6/gcc_64/lib -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make:[cfgtest_QtWidgets] Error 1
```

any idea?
`

Answer (score 1):

The interesting part of the error message is `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL`, which means libgl was not found.

You're aware you can simply install PyQt5 via `apt-get install python3-pyqt5`? If you really have a reason to build it by hand, you can tell apt-get to install all build dependencies via `apt-get build-dep python3-pyqt5`.

This will also install `libgl1`/`libgl1-mesa-glx` which is the missing bit here.